# Create Subsite in OFFICE 365

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, event-receivers, office-365, workflow-activity

I want to create Subsites based on some custom list in OFFICE 365.
It is one time job.
I am planning to have one customlist which will contain title,template,inherit permision flag,inherit master page flag and so on.
once the record is inserted in the list, expectation is - new subsite with the provided title.

what is my best friend as i cant use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges in OFFICE 365.
is it event receiver, worklfow, webpart,App.
if some one can provide me an example or guide me on how to .

Thanks for replying Biju.
let me know if i need to give more details.

Thanks,
Devang

Comment: Let me have little more details on your question. When do you want to create sub sites? What is the nature of the job? Is it a repeated job or one time job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify NewItem.aspx of the custom list, and when user clicks on Save button to insert a new list item, fire up your custom JSOM code that creates the subsite based on the details given on the NewItem form.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not added a sub site in this manner, reading from other sources, I understand that we can use

> Remote Event Handler

or

> auto hosted app with workflow

to do this in SharePoint Online.

[Remote event receivers for cloud apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220048.aspx)

[Similar questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67022/event-receiver-site-creation) are already answered in this community and have a look at them before you proceed.

Hope this helps

Comment: i will give this a try.auto hosted app with workflow is new to me so it might be little tough for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create subsite or list from workflow you can use custom 3rd party activities for Office 365:

- [Create list](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/docs/activities-description/#CreateList) - create list from custom template
- [Create web](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/docs/activities-description/#CreateWeb) - create web from custom template

You can automatically start the workflow when item created and create subsite or list.

**Note:** Activities are included in the paid [Workflow Activity Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/) developed by my team.